# Ask sample of size and dimension of variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I have a question from my textbook. It said Let $\mathbf{X_1,X_2,...,X_{20}}$ be a random sample of size n=20 from an $N_6(\mathbf{\mu, \Sigma})$ population. Then the distribution of $\mathbf{\bar{X}}$ is $N_6(\mathbf{\mu, 1/20*\Sigma})$

My question: I am confused by 6 and 20 here. What is 6? What is 20? Also, $\mathbf{X_1,X_2,...,X_{20}}$ here we have 20 X's. Also, the sample of size n=20. Is this coincidence?

Comment: If notation is standard, then you have a sample of size 20 form a 6-dimensional normal distribution.

Comment: How to understand sample size in this case? My understanding is still staying on the data set (data frame) in Stata or R. Say, my variables are height and weight. And I ask 20 people. So my data frame is 20 rows and 2 columns. These 20 rows are called sample size.

Comment: @Mariana Your data frame has 20 rows and 6 columns. Each row is a 6-dimensional vector following the $N_6(\mu, \Sigma)$ distribution; the rows are $X_1, \ldots, X_{20}$.

Comment: In your 6-dimensional example you might have perhaps have height, weight, waist circumference, arm length, leg length, neck circumference